# AngularJS + UI Router: route with variable parameter and specific value handling (exceptions)

Tags: angularjs

There is probably a better way to refer to this issue but I can't think of it at the moment.

I'm posting this to hopefully help anyone who ends up having this situation pop up. I couldn't find an answer anywhere when I was trying to figure this out.

**The issue:**
You have a state with one or more variable parameters.
**Ex:** /arg1/arg2/:var1

But there are exceptions where :var1 has a specific deviation from the norm you establish with that state .

In other words, :var1 can be anything except "foo". If :var1 == foo (/arg1/arg2/foo), then you need to handle that state differently.

My specific case for this was with a state url like: /arg1/arg2/arg3/:var1/arg4/:var2/:var3 where :var3 had an exception if it was "exact" (/arg1/arg2/arg3/:var1/arg4/:var2/exact).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple but may not be completely (or immediately) obvious.

Place the exception state above the fully variable state.

In other words:

```
.state('stateexception',{url:'/arg1/arg2/foo'})
.state('fullvarstate',{url:'/arg1/arg2/:var1'})
```